# Django rest framework, returning item status booked or free based on current date/time

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, logic

I am currently working on a website for my students where it will help them to book some items on the classroom. I am already done with the booking logic and form so no two students are allowed to book the same item at the same time. I would like to create a table for them where it shows the item name and the status of the item based on the current time. So I have a webpage/django view that have a list of all the booking made including the item name, starting date, ending date, and the person who booked the item. So, based on this booking list, I would like to create some logic that will go through this booking list and compare it against the current time/date. In simple words, if the current time/date falls in between the start and end date of a booked item , it should return the value "booked" other wise "free". I am not sure how to achieve this. I brainstormed for days, and search the Internet for some hints but nothing. I would be very thankful if someone helped me. This is my models:

```
class Items(models.Model):
   ITEMS_CATEGORIES=(
        ('item-1', 'item-1'),
        ('item-2', 'item-2'),
        ('item-3', 'item-3'),
        ('item-4', 'item-4'),
        ('item-5', 'item-5'),
          ) 
    category = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=ITEM_CATEGORIES)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.category

class Booking(models.Model):
   
    user = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=False)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='SOMESTRING')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Subsystem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    check_in = models.DateTimeField()
    check_out = models.DateTimeField()
  
   
    def __str__(self):
       return f' {self.item} is booked successfully by {self.user} from {self.check_in.strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M")} to {self.check_out.strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M")} for {self.note} '
```

So I thought of something like this but this code 100% is wrong, but something similar to this

```
serializers:
class BookingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Booking
    fields = (
      'item','check_in','check_out', 'user'
    )
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()

                 /
                 /
                 some logic //
     if current_time = (check_in and check_out)
        return "Booked"
    else
       return "Free"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [**`SerializerMethodField`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to add another field that returns a value from a calculation you need:

```
import django.utils import timezone


class BookingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    status = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = (
            'item', 'check_in', 'check_out', 'user', 'status'
        )

    def get_status(self, obj):
        return 'Booked' if obj.check_in <= timezone.now() < obj.check_out else 'Free'
```

Comment: Hey, when I run the codes I receive this error: "can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes".

Comment: Updated. Try to use `timezone.now()`

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. I have a quick question. Please note I am new to Django, can I import this serializer for example in another serializer ? So that the fields of this serializer shows there, even though both are from different models?

Comment: Yes you can. As long as that other model has `check_in`, `check_out` fields. Also you need to define status as a field in the other serializer as well

Comment: Perefect, thank you so much Brian. I will try to add both check_in, check_out fields as foreign key in the other model. Hope it will work ☺.

Comment: Hmm that would not work exactly with a foreign key. Both those fields needs to be `DateTimeField`s in the other model as well

Comment: Okay, I can do that but how will they be linked to the Booking check_in, check_out fields?

Comment: I think it will be better for the other serializer to have its own calculation on this field. But hard to say without seeing the models. Maybe you can post that as another question so other people can see it as well

Comment: Thank you. I did post the details, hope its clear. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69263707/importing-django-seriliazer-fields-into-another-seriliazer-feilds

Comment: No worries :) will have a look at your new question later